# Switching a VirtualBox Ubuntu Server VM from UEFI to BIOS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, bios, grub2, uefi

I have a virtual machine running in VirtualBox of Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS x64. When I initially set it up, I configured the VM to use EFI instead of BIOS.

But, it turns out VirtualBox's implementation of EFI is buggy and incomplete, so I'd like to switch it back to BIOS. However, turning off EFI for the VM fails to boot with an error stating it can't find any bootable media.

I tried to run the rescue mode of the Ubuntu Server installer. When I try to reinstall Grub, which I'm guessing is the right action, it fails. I'm trying to install it to `/dev/mapper/vm--vg-root` which is where `/` is listed as mounted when the VM does run.

So, how do I properly transition this VM from UEFI back to BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

To change the fireware from UEFI to Bios follow the below command in VBoxManage command line interface.

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --firmware bios
```

Comment: The problem is I set up the VM itself initially as EFI, so grub and everything got set up with that assumption. When I change the VM back to BIOS, it doesn't find anything to boot and halts the system.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Set_up_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode

Comment: Thank you; after many tries, that tool worked and I switched the VM from EFI to BIOS.